# Shortcut keys for writing scipts for AWS Glue Studio Jobs

Tags: aws-glue

Writing Python code directly in the development area that AWS Glue studio provides is sometimes inevitable because of some limitations that company has.
I could not find any document for the provided shortcut keys by Amazon as we have in our IDEs.
I found the following shortcut keys so far by trial and error: (Windows keyboard)

**Ctrl + /** : toggle for commenting/uncommenting current line (where cursor located) or more lines if selected
**F2** : toggle for collapsing/expanding current block of code
**F3** : opens search box like browser's search

Anyone knows any other shortcuts to add here or is there any document for this?

**Note**: Of course, I don't mean some obvious shortcuts like Ctrl+C for copy, Ctrl+v for paste, Ctrl+x for cut, Ctrl+z for undo, Ctrl+y for redo.